# Javascript comparing line ending values

Tags: javascript, character

I am trying to compare the line ending values that are saved in a DB, with `'\r\n'`, `'\r'` and `'\n'`.  Is this possible? Or is there another way. This is doesn't work...

```
if (value === "\r\n") {
    return "carriageReturnNewLine";
}
if (value === "\r") {
    return "carriageReturn";
}
if (value === "\n") {
    return "newLine";
}
```

Comment: What is `value` when you dump it out to the console.  For example, `console.log(JSON.stringify(value))`?

Comment: When i do JSON.stringify(value) I do get "\r\n".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with the String match() method and a regular expression:

```
if (value.match(/\r\n/)) {
    return "carriageReturnNewLine";
}
if (value.match(/\r/)) {
    return "carriageReturn";
}
if (value.match(/\n/)) {
    return "newLine";
}
```

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match